# Assembly syntax Error: in instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

This is how my code looks like. Do you see any problems with it?

```
compare macro nr1,nr2 ; title of macro
local et1,et2  ; etiquetes
mov eax,nr1
mov ebx nr2
push eax
push ebx

; here I compare the 2 number nr1, nr2 to see whether is bigger

cmp eax,ebx      ; comparing the 2 numbers
ja et1
jb et2
et1:
sub eax,ebx        ; if the first one is bigger, we substract from it

; here we subtract from the bigger one

push eax
push offset format3
call printf
add esp,8

 et2:

sub ebx,eax         ; if the second one is bigger we substract like this
push ebx
push offset format3
call printf
add esp,8
add esp, 8
endm
```

Comment: do you get any error messages? If so, on which line?

Comment: This line `mov ebx nr2` seems to be missing a comma.

Comment: Your assembler certainly sees problems with it, and is telling you. Why not pay attention to it? It's certainly quicker than asking a question on Stack Overflow!

Comment: well, the comma was the problem, actually. the problem is that the assembler was showing another line for the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov ebx nr2
```

Obviously this line needs a comma. Actually the comma could have been included legally in the calling sequence of this macro! That's why the assembler was showing the error on another line.

But also :
Shouldn't you jump over the *et2* block when the *et1* block was executed?
What's the sense of pushing EAX and EBX if they're not popped afterwards? (The stack is balanced though)

Comment: yes, I will work on that too. I will post my whole code. because I have a tricky problem. I have to read from 2 files and print the number of the words in it. it works for each file but when I put both files, it fails